# Point plot with drawings in it and abbreviations

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I am very inexperienced with latex and tikz, but I need a diagram for my work. I've tried many examples, but the result never looked good. So I hope that one of you can write me a template. The result should look something like this:

[image]

It would also be best if the dots were described using shapes or abbreviations instead of colors. I would be very grateful if someone could write me a template that I can add to.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I think your question is asking a bit too much of people who give their time up on here for nothing, so you are unlikely to get exactly what you're looking for. However, I'll post an answer to help you to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following code will help to get you started. The `pgfplots` package is pretty versatile, and you can find a lot of examples of things here: http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0,ymax=0.3,xmin=0,xmax=600,
             legend style={at={(0,-0.2)},
                           anchor=north west,
                           legend columns=2},
             grid=major,
             xlabel=Runtime in sec,
             ylabel=Costs in US Dollar,
             title=MIX]
    \addplot[
        scatter/classes={
            a={mark=square*,blue},%
            b={mark=triangle*,red},%
            c={mark=*,green},%
            d={mark=x,black}%
        },
        scatter,only marks,
        scatter src=explicit symbolic]
        coordinates {
            (300,0.25)   [a]
            (462,0.05)   [b]
            (370,0.1)    [c]
            (520,0.06)   [d]
        };
    \legend{Class a,Class b,Class c,Class d}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Chart with four data points]

The idea here is to use the `classes` to give each point their own style (in this case, `a`, `b`, `c` or `d`), and you can then detail what they should be in the `\legend` command.

One thing I haven't addressed here is the red blob around some of the data points. It may be worth doing a bit of searching to see if there are any good examples that you can adapt, otherwise it might be worthy of a question in its own right. In such an event, please post a minimal working example (MWE) so that people who might help you have something to go by (see: [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)).

Comment: thanks a lot for your help